# MIPS Assembly: Sum of ascending (and descending) consecutive numbers

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

In MIPS Assembly language I need to write a function which calculates ascending and descending consecutive numbers.

Given array "A" and integers "a, b, n" write a function that:

```
if(a < b)
     A[0] = A[0] + a
     A[1] = A[1] + b
     A[2] = A[2] + a
     A[3] = A[3] + b
     ...
     A[2n-1] = A[2n-1] + b
else
     A[0] = A[0] + b
     A[1] = A[1] + a
     A[2] = A[2] + b
     A[3] = A[3] + a
     ...
     A[2n-1] = A[2n-1] + a
```

Got no idea how to proceed next. The architecture address is 32 bit long.

I started by declarations: $a0 = a, $a1 = b, $a2 = n, $a3 = A

Then:

```
     add $t0, $a3, $a3 #stopping condition
     xor $t1, $t1, $t1 # index = 0
     slt $t2, $a0, $a1 # if a0 less than a1, then set t2 = 1, else, t2 = 0
     bne $t2, $0, foo1 # if t2 != 0 then branch to foo1, which is the (a < b) sum loop
```

Comment: `xor $t1, $t1, $t1` is not an efficient way to zero a register in MIPS.  It works, but is has no advantage and some disadvantages (false dependency on `$t1`, as required by the memory model to preserve data dependency ordering, the CPU feature that C++11 `memory_order_consume` was intended to expose.)  XOR-zeroing is an x86 thing, and maybe some other ISAs with variable-length instructions.  Use `li $t1, 1`, which will assemble to something like `addiu $t1, $zero, 0`, not reading any registers other than `$zero`.

Comment: I'd write one loop, and `if(a<b) swap a, b`

Answer (score 0):

> Got no idea how to proceed next.

There are two parts you'll want to address:

1. The first part is that the code your showing uses ...'s , which is very informal: so much so that it is effectively incomplete code.  This is not really a standard approach to writing pseudo code, but it is a start.  Suggest, then to finish that code so as to remove the ...'s parts.  You'll probably want to use a loop of some sort to do this.  Suggest to do this using either more formal pseudo code (i.e. without ...'s), or better yet in working C code so you can test it; you'll need to have this before you can translate that into assembly, and I reiterate that the best approach here is to do this *before attempting the assembly version*, so you know what code you'll be trying to write for the assembly.
2. The second part is a matter of decomposing the problem: What do you need to know so you can translate your pseudo code into assembly?

You might have to learn concepts of if-then-else statement in MIPS, array references in MIPS, assignment statements, and function signatures and MIPS parameter passing.

Each of these items can be studied independently of the total program you're trying to write, and each has extensive writeups here on stackoverflow, though many other websites have similar instruction on MIPS assembly.

---

Once you have working pseudo or C code (without the ...'s), have learned if-then-else, loops, array references, and a function with parameters, you can translate the code you have line by line into assembly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ill try to work from here.